# Extremely basic HTML formatting

Tags: css, html, css-float, css-position

I'm pulling my hair out here. I just want two divs side by side containing content that resizes the divs and their containing divs based on the content with all content visible, no scroll.

The following markup isn't my site but I have written it to demonstrate what I want:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>

<style>

#outer{
    width:400px;
}

#innerleft{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}

#innerright{
    width:200px;
    color:#900;
    float:left;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="innerleft">
        sdgfjfdbvkjfdbvkjfdbvkjdfbvkjdfbvkjdfbvkjdbvkjdfbvkjdfbvkjdfbvkjdfbvkjdfbjkfbvjkdfbdfkjdfbjkfdbkjdfjvfjkbfvbjkfvkjbvbfjdjdfdfbdfj
    </div>
    <div id="innerright">
        dsufbjksvkudfsvkdfubvjkdfhbvkhdfbvksdbvkjsdbvkjdsbvkjsbdvkjbsdvkjbsdkjvbskjvbsdkjvbskdjbvksdbvksdjvbkjdsbvkjsbvkjsdbvkjdsbvkjdsksbdjv
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I seem to have tried everything!

Answer (score 5):

Apply `word-wrap`:

```
#outer > div
{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NEbj7/1/

Comment: I had never heard of that! Thanks! I'll mark correct as soon as I can.

Comment: @AdamWaite No worries :) I'm assuming this is test content you're using then considering the length? In future you might find it easier to use "[Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/feed/html)" text

Answer (score 0):

To make it automatically resize you want to add more -- % percentage to make it automatically fill the space

```
#outer{
    width:100%; /* 100% */
}

#innerleft{
    width:50%; /* 50% */
    float:left;
    word-break:break-all; /* Lines may break between any two characters for non-CJK scripts */
}

#innerright{
    width:50%;  /* 50% */
    color:#900;
    float:left;
    word-break:break-all;  /* Lines may break between any two characters for non-CJK scripts */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eZpvr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Browsers by default won't wrap the text which doesn't have any white space in it. To force the browser to wrap the text you must add the word-wrap property to #innerleft and #innerright

```
#innerleft, #innerright{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

reference: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap